# FTP download from an URL block the web site

Tags: php, html, ftp, download

I'm using this PHP code on a file to open a dialog box to download a video

```
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=full.mp4");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile('ftp://login:pwd@exemple.com/video/2011/full.mp4');
exit;
```

Everything works fine **except that** during the download (150Mo video) I can not navigate on the web site. I have to wait for the download to complete (or to pause the download) to have the web site back for navigation ! (Even if I open a new tab and I try to open an URL on the web site)

Is there something that I'm doing wrong ?

I'm on a dedicated server.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Does not support threads, it's single threaded, so you have to wait until the scripts finishes executing, in this case, until it finishes downloading that file to continue using your site. As a quick fix, you can host that file in other server, external to your site, and call that file from your site.